# While I am trying to deploy LWC component I am getting error as "Value too long for field" in VS code.Does anyone have solution for this

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli

```
force-app\main\default\lwc\sampleLWC\sampleLWC.js-meta.xml  Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/sample/sample.js] of Lightning Component Bundle [sampleLWC]. 

Error: Value too long for field: Source maximum length is:131072
    force-app\main\default\lwc\sampleLWC\sampleLWC.js           No base file for markup://c:partsOrderLWC
```

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282862/lwc-file-size-restriction-on-js-file. Is your `sample.js` code long? The 131072 limit would handle 5,000 or more lines of code, but would be a problem with large volumes of data.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the salesforce latest plugins with the below command. This issue is resolved in latest release. I have faced same problem, I fixed it with below cammand.

`sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@latest`

Comment: This did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this discussion post:
[LWC: File size restriction on js file](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282862/lwc-file-size-restriction-on-js-file)

You might need to break your LWC component into multiples to resolve this error.