# Failed to save Lightning Component - Value too long for field

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, deployment

I'm getting the following error When I deploy my codebase.

It shows `Value too long for field: Source maximum length is:131072`. I could able to find the solution.

Is there any configuration change need to done to increase the length, Please help me on this. Thanks.

```
=== Deploy Errors
PROJECT PATH                                                      ERRORS                                                                                                                                                                                         
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\lwc\ProjectV1\ProjectV1.js-meta.xml  Failed to save Lightning Component Resource [lwc/ProjectV1/ProjectV1.html] of Lightning Component Bundle [ProjectV1]. Error: Value too long for field: Source maximum length is:131072
```

Comment: Can't you split it?

Answer (score 1):

This limit indicates that your configuration file is too large. While not documented that I know of, this error isn't one you can bypass. You'll need to reduce the complexity of your metadata to fit within this limit, probably by using multiple components. It sounds like your current component is entirely too complex if you need a configuration file this large.